# Writing large number of rows using jxls to excel in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxls

I am using the below code to to write data to excel

XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();

```
        InputStream is = this.getServlet().getServletContext()
                .getResourceAsStream(templateFilePath);
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = (HSSFWorkbook) transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);
```

But but the system hangs after HSSFWorkbook workBook = (HSSFWorkbook) transformer.transformXLS(is, beans); if number of rows is more than 1500. Is there any other way or suggetsion for writing data  using template and beans objects for large data sets

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade to Jxls-2 and use SXSSF Transformer support.
The code may look like this

```
            Transformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createSxssfTransformer(workbook, 100, false);
            AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
            List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
            Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
            xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Result!A1"), context);
```

See full example in [jxls-demo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/bf8abea25a2e86b2e21d0067b1b6e7eb737a7274/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/SxssfDemo.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).
Please note that this approach assumes some template restrictions given that only a subset of rows is kept in memory (in particular regarding to formula evaluation).

If you do not need formulas it is recommended to disable formula processing using  `context.getConfig().setIsFormulaProcessingRequired(false);`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use SXSSF - the streaming version of the POI workbook.  This is a guess.

Comment: using SXXF i cant use template and bean object,